# How to create a unique GUID in intersystem's cache?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

Looking through the documentation I don't see a GUID datatype.  Is there a function or something to generate a random GUID?  What is it?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a way to get the C# tag on this question?  I think if you gave some C# code samples you could really bring in some up votes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$System.Util.CreateGUID()
```

This doesn't return a data-type however, it's just a string.  You can write your own data-type class if you need special validation or conversion between logical/display/ODBC.